# regular expressions escape on character

Tags: java, regex

I have to separate a big list of emails and names, I have to split on commas but some names have commas in them so I have to deal with that first. Luckily the names are between "quotes".

At the moment I get with my regex output like this for example (edit: it doesn't display emails in the forum I see!):

```
"Talboom, Esther"

"Wolde, Jos van der"

"Debbie Derksen"  <deberken@casema.nl>,   corine  <corine5@xs4all.nl>, "
```

The last one went wrong cause the name had no comma so it continues until it founds one and that was the one i want to use to separate. So I want it to look until it finds '<'.
How can I do that?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

String test = "\"Talboom, Esther\" <E.Talboom@wegener.nl>,     \"Wolde, Jos van der\" <J.vdWolde@wegener.nl>,   \"Debbie Derksen\"  <deberken@casema.nl>,   corine  <corine5@xs4all.nl>, \"Markies Aart\" <A.Markies@wegenernieuwsmedia.nl>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\".*?,.*?\"");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find ()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

edit:
better line to work with since not all have a name or quotes:

```
String test = "\"Talboom, Esther\" <E.Talboom@wegener.nl>,     DRP - Wouter Haan <wouter@drp.eu>, \"Wolde, Jos van der\" <J.vdWolde@wegener.nl>,   \"Debbie Derksen\"  <deberken@casema.nl>,   corine  <corine5@xs4all.nl>, clankilllller@gmail.com, \"Markies Aart\" <A.Markies@wegenernieuwsmedia.nl>";
```

Answer (score 2):

I would simplify the code by using `String.split` and `String.replaceAll`. This avoids the hassle of working with a `Pattern` and makes the code neat and brief.
Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "\"Talboom, Esther\" <E.Talboom@wegener.nl>,     \"Wolde, Jos van der\" <J.vdWolde@wegener.nl>,   \"Debbie Derksen\"  <deberken@casema.nl>,   corine  <corine5@xs4all.nl>, \"Markies Aart\" <A.Markies@wegenernieuwsmedia.nl>";

    // Split up into each person's details
    String[] nameEmailPairs = test.split(",\\s*(?=\")");
    for (String nameEmailPair : nameEmailPairs) {
        // Extract exactly the parts you need from the person's details
        String name = nameEmailPair.replaceAll("\"([^\"]+)\".*", "$1");
        String email = nameEmailPair.replaceAll(".*<([^>]+).*", "$1");
        System.out.println(name + " = " + email);
    }
}
```

Output, showing it actually works :)

```
Talboom, Esther = E.Talboom@wegener.nl
Wolde, Jos van der = J.vdWolde@wegener.nl
Debbie Derksen = corine5@xs4all.nl
Markies Aart = A.Markies@wegenernieuwsmedia.nl
```

Comment: I was using the same regex than you before -- until I saw that it would fail for (legal) names such as `"me,"`.

Comment: @fge Often it's easier to do these things in *two* steps - it tends to keep the regex still readable, and is easier to understand, debug and maintain

Comment: Also, `.split()` will internally use a `Pattern`, with the difference that it will have to create a new one for each `split()` invocation -- might as well use a Pattern and its provided `split()` method ;)

Comment: Yes, which is exactly what I do -- see my solution

Comment: Because it's easier to read, you should tend to use an API before rewriting it yourself. BTW, internally `Pattern.compile` (which `String.split` uses) caches the `Patterns`, so you don't need your `static Pattern` - performance is virtually the same without it.

Comment: I didn't know patterns would be cached, but anyway -- this doesn't prevent the regex to fail on `"me," <me@me.com>` ;)

Comment: Actually, `Pattern.compile()` *doesn't* cache, and neither do any other Pattern methods or the Pattern-related methods in String (e.g. `split()`).  If you want to use the same Pattern object twice without re-compiling, you have to maintain a reference to it yourself.  (`java.util.Scanner` caches the Patterns it uses, but only for its own use.)

Comment: Not all emails have a name in front or quotes so i added a better test string at the bottom of my first post. With that one it only finds 4 out of 7.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks for pointing my misunderstanding out. I always thought it did cache them (years ago "some bloke told me so"). Merry Xmas